# How to exit an application on Windows Phone 8 programmatically

Tags: windows-phone-8, devextreme

I am creating an application in which when i press the cancel button the application should close.
for that I have used " navigator.app.exitApp()" statement as given a solution in stack overflow.

This solution is working in android but it is not working in windows phone 8.
Windows phone is throwing exception that "Unable to get property 'exitApp' of undefined or null reference"

I have written following code for this.

```
cancelLogin: function () {
        var result = DevExpress.ui.dialog.confirm('Do you want to exit ?', 'Confirm Exit');
        result.done(function (dialogResult) {
            try {
                if (dialogResult === true) {
                    navigator.app.exitApp();
                }
            }
            catch (e) {
                DevExpress.ui.dialog.alert(e.message, 'Exception');
            }
        });
   }
```

this works fine in android but not working in windows phone.
how can I close an application programetically in windows phone 8 ??

Answer (score 1):

The exitApp method is not supported by Cordova APIs for Windows Phone 8. To solve the problem, please execute the following code for the Windows Phone 8 platform:

```
window.external.Notify("DevExpress.ExitApp");
```

If you create a Windows Phone application using the DevExtreme wizard, the required code will be automatically generated.

```
    if(device.platform === "win8" && device.phone) {
        defaultLayout = "simple";
        startupView = "Navigation";
        $.each(Application1.config.navigation, function (i, item) { item.root = false; });
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

function onDeviceReady() {
        document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
}

function onBackKeyDown() {
     if(Application1.app.canBack()) {
            Application1.app.back();
      }
      else {
            if(window.external) {
                window.external.Notify("DevExpress.ExitApp");
            }
        }
}
```

Thanks,